# Translation not loaded on multimodule shared components - Angular 5

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, multi-module, ngx-translate

I have following problem. I created multimodule project with Angular 5 and would like to load translations dynamically for lazy loaded modules. Let's say my structure is like this:

```
app
 ->app.module.ts
 ->shared-components
  ->shared.components.module.ts and components
 ->lazy-loaded-module1.ts
 ->lazy-loaded-module2.ts
```

Now I have shared app.translation.module.ts between app.module.ts and shared.components.module.ts so my app.translation.module looks like this:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/core/', '.json');
}

const translationOptions = {
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
    deps: [HttpClient],
    isolate: true
  }
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot(translationOptions)],
  exports: [TranslateModule],
  providers: [TranslateService]
})
export class AppTranslationModule {
}
```

The problem starts when I want to use component from shared components in one of lazy loaded modules (they have their own translations with TranslationModule.forChild()). It appears that somehow shared component no longer uses its own translation module and starts to use one of parents module which in my opinion is not acceptable since I would have to clone translations among all modules that use shared components which makes it not usable at all. Am I making something wrong? What should be proper configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Make one SharedModule that imports translate module and import that SharedModule to SharedComponentModule. 
An Example:

SharedModule.ts

```
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';    
@NgModule({
   exports: [
       TranslateModule,
   ],
providers: [],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

SharedComponentModule.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
       SharedModule
   ],
})
export class SharedComponentModule { }
```

Comment: That is old question and yours answer would not work anyway ;) In used version of ngx-translate there was no option of merging translation which basically is the case here.

Comment: I had problem with current version and was unable to load translations by putting common components in SharedModule. I found this question without any answer and find the solution for current version.

Comment: I still think that you can use one or the other instance of TranslateService, they got replaced anyway. My solution to that was to not isolate TranslateServices and use Singleton instead with merge translations option enabled. This way I didn't get IMO redundant instances of translation service, yet had all needed translations in place with lazy loaded modules